# Port no.s in TCP/IP packets

Tags: ethernet, tcp

I am learning TCP/IP basics. I made a server-client chat application in which server opens a port 1024 and client can send message to it. I am a bit confused about the contents of TCP/IP packets exchanged by server and client.  If client sends a message to server, it goes as packets via ethernet. In the ethernet frame from client, data field is encoded in TCP/IP format. In the TCP/IP frame, destination port will be 1024. But what will be source port's value ? Client is opening no port. Only server opens a port. Also I would like to know if there is any way to monitor these TCP/IP packets sent and received in PC.

Comment: It's not that "the client is opening no port", the operating system will bind your client process to some available port at that time i.e. it's just that you are not specifically asking for a particular port on client side and the operating system binds your client process to an available port at that time

Comment: Server needs to be able to respond to the client so normally that means the client picks a random port and tells the server it can send it’s responses there. Wireshark is propably the best tool for monitoring https://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: The client is indeed opening a port. Have a look at a `netstat` output on the client host after it has connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget there's [multiple layers involve here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). TCP, IP and Ethernet are on different ones even if they are often used in conjunction. The separation is important to keep in mind. Ethernet (layer 2) is a protocol that connects individual computers together, but it doesn't care what IP addresses they have. IP connects computers over a much larger scale, it can be routed and sent over a variety of "layer two" network technologies where Ethernet is but one of those.

The great thing about IETF internet protocols is they're all [thoroughly documented](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793) so you can find out how they work internally. In the case of TCP, which operates on top of IP, the port numbers are in the TCP layer. IP itself doesn't care about them, it's only concerned about source and destination addresses.

The key is right here in the diagram that describes the TCP header:

```
  0                   1                   2                   3
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |          Source Port          |       Destination Port        |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                        Sequence Number                        |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                    Acknowledgment Number                      |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |  Data |           |U|A|P|R|S|F|                               |
   | Offset| Reserved  |R|C|S|S|Y|I|            Window             |
   |       |           |G|K|H|T|N|N|                               |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |           Checksum            |         Urgent Pointer        |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                    Options                    |    Padding    |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                             data                              |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

Both source and destination port *must* be populated. This is a key component of how your system's IP stack tracks which packets pertain to which connections.

Normally when you write code that connects to a server your connection originates from a (somewhat) random source port. When you create a server process that listens on a port, then that port can be automatically assigned or set specifically.

For services like HTTP you'd want that port pinned to 80 if you want other clients to connect to that service, so automatic assignment is of no help. Sometimes automatic assignment is preferable so there's no conflicts.

You can monitor all of this with tools like [`tcpdump`](http://www.tcpdump.org) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) among many others. They can dig into the various layers and show what's going on.

Comment: Thanks.  I created a TCP Server and Client Application in VB and successfully sent/receive data between Client and Server. The Server is using port 1234 in my home wifi network in my laptop. However Wireshark is not showing the frames I exchange between the client and server in that port. I checked command prompt, Port 1234 is shown active there. What could be the reason ?

Comment: Make sure you're "listening" on the correct interface. It's easy to mistakenly listen on the ethernet port when using WiFi and vice versa. Those are two different hardware interfaces, and the "loopback" or localhost interface is often a third one.

Comment: Both are in localhost 127.0.0.1. So it has nothing to do with my wifi?

Comment: Precisely. When you send traffic to localhost it goes over the loopback interface, usually `lo`, `lo0` or something like it depending on your operating system. The network stack directs IP traffic through the appropriate device depending on your routing table, so if you're listening on the wrong device you won't see it. Sometimes there's a "listen to all interfaces" option but that can be like a fire-hose, so be careful.

Comment: You were right. I had to use some other software called RawCap to capture loopback frames and dump it into a pcap file. Wireshark can open that file :-).

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right track now. Hope that helped.

Comment: I have this doubt. My laptop is currently connected to wifi and has some IP address associated with it. I previously used that IP address in my local client application. So frames didnt show up in wireshark or RawCap. Now I changed it to localhost 127.0.0.1, so now frames can be captured by RawCap. Suppose my client application was in some other PC on the same wifi, I should use my laptop's IP address in client application right?

Comment: If you're using DHCP, which is common, your IP address might switch around periodically, as often as every time you connect. Also on many networks you can only capture traffic going directly through your machine, so trying to capture traffic for another IP is not going to work. Testing on your localhost address is the easiest way to ensure you're getting all the traffic. You can also use a non-encrypting proxy (SOCKS5, etc.) to force-route the traffic through your computer.

Answer (score 1):

Port number is a logical entity/number used to identify a process running in server/client. Just like your server application has a port number ( which you decided ), client application will also have some port number associated with it, as assigned by the OS. Type in **netstat -ab** in cmd prompt, you can see the port number associated with your client application, in the list of processes and corresponding port numbers given by the command.